# How to get Channel ID of videos listed in PlaylistItems in Youtube API v3?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

When I try to list videos with `playlistItems.list`, I seem to not be getting the `channelId` of the video anywhere. The video owner is different than the playlist owner, mind you.

[Here is an example in Google API Explorer](https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.playlistItems.list?part=snippet%252CcontentDetails&maxResults=1&playlistId=PLgMGySfO8dl_IybGLflF1QhHwhBkOyZg7&fields=etag%252CeventId%252Citems%252Ckind%252CnextPageToken%252CpageInfo%252CprevPageToken%252CtokenPagination%252CvisitorId&_h=7&)

I'm requesting one item from the playlist with an ID of `PLgMGySfO8dl_IybGLflF1QhHwhBkOyZg7`. The one item returned is a video with an ID of `tDHxiDA1Y6s`. I'm expecting to see the channel with an ID of `UCOfEKi7Qkc3g5XNoQSl3D8Q` somewhere, but I don't see it.

I do see `UC1bSfMYJEqh7DTSOsbe_t8Q` as a channel ID, but that's the channel ID of the owner of the playlist, not of the video. Also I noticed in the fields editor that there should be a field `snippet.resourceId.channelId`, but even if I have it selected to be included, as you can see in the example result below, I do not get any value there.

Is there any way to get the channel IDs included of the videos without a second request?

This is the result I get:

`{
 "kind": "youtube#playlistItemListResponse",
 "etag": "\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/rEUHufzTzfkJMLVrD2pBtEz5OWY\"",
 "nextPageToken": "CAEQAA",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 30,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {
   "kind": "youtube#playlistItem",
   "etag": "\"XI7nbFXulYBIpL0ayR_gDh3eu1k/2VurTVExuTlDwFHQ3ULfjL-KM7U\"",
   "id": "UExnTUd5U2ZPOGRsX0l5YkdMZmxGMVFoSHdoQmtPeVpnNy41NkI0NEY2RDEwNTU3Q0M2",
   "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": "2018-05-26T11:37:02.000Z",
    "channelId": "UC1bSfMYJEqh7DTSOsbe_t8Q",
    "title": "Unreal Tournament - Soundtrack (UMX)",
    "description": "Music by Alexander \"Siren\" Brandon and Michiel van den Bos.\n\"enigma\", \"seeker\", \"seeker2\" by Daniel \"Basehead\" Gardopée.\n\"FireBreath\" by Tero \"Teque\" Kostermaa and Kaj-Eerik \"Nitro\" Komppa.\n\"mechanism eight\" by Andrew \"Necros\" Sega.\n\"Razorback // Unreal mix\" by Peter \"Skaven\" Hajba.\n\nTracks:\n00:00  BOTPACK #9(By Michiel)\n04:51  BOTMCA#10 (By Michiel)\n09:13  Cannonade\n11:11  Colossus (Michiel)\n15:30  The Course\n20:01  Room of Champions\n22:17  Shared Dig\n28:03  Into the darkness (Ending.umx)\n29:53  unreal add-on (enigma)\n33:19  -xTREMELY xECUTABLE-\n35:31  FireBreath\n38:48  Foregone Destruction\n43:02  Go Down\n46:05  Guardian\n47:50  Nightvision - Sandman/KFM\n51:58  Lock\n54:44  mechanism eight - necros\n1:01:38  Mission Landing\n1:05:53  Nether Animal\n1:10:56  Organic\n1:14:01  Phantom\n1:20:04  Razorback // Unreal mix\n1:24:56  RipCord\n1:27:08  Riverb3\n1:29:05  Run\n1:33:41  Dream Tear Down\n1:38:54  Save Me (SaveMe.umx)\n1:40:47  Save Me (Savemeg.umx)\n1:42:41  unreal add-on (seeker)\n1:46:34  unreal add-on (seeker2)\n1:50:01  Skyward Fire\n1:55:00  Into the darkness (Strider.umx)\n1:57:45  Submarinebase 2\n2:01:51  SuperFist\n2:03:51  Underworld II\n2:07:02  Unreal Tournament Menu\n2:09:04  Unreal Tournament Title\n2:10:33  Three Wheels Turning\n\nA few titles and credits information taken from the Liandri Archives.",
    "thumbnails": {
     "default": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tDHxiDA1Y6s/default.jpg",
      "width": 120,
      "height": 90
     },
     "medium": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tDHxiDA1Y6s/mqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 320,
      "height": 180
     },
     "high": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tDHxiDA1Y6s/hqdefault.jpg",
      "width": 480,
      "height": 360
     },
     "standard": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tDHxiDA1Y6s/sddefault.jpg",
      "width": 640,
      "height": 480
     },
     "maxres": {
      "url": "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/tDHxiDA1Y6s/maxresdefault.jpg",
      "width": 1280,
      "height": 720
     }
    },
    "channelTitle": "amcsi",
    "playlistId": "PLgMGySfO8dl_IybGLflF1QhHwhBkOyZg7",
    "position": 0,
    "resourceId": {
     "kind": "youtube#video",
     "videoId": "tDHxiDA1Y6s"
    }
   },
   "contentDetails": {
    "videoId": "tDHxiDA1Y6s",
    "videoPublishedAt": "2011-05-02T19:50:49.000Z"
   }
  }
 ]
}`

Comment: I'm afraid that you have to do another request for it. As you've experienced, playlistItem contains little details regarding the video so it is expected to call [Videos: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) to get that detail (ChannelID).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suspected, a call to PlaylistItems returns the channel ID of the playlist owner. To get the original channel ID of the videos in the playlist, you'll need a second call to the videos endpoint with the video IDs.

Answer (score 1):

They have added the fields '**videoOwnerChannelTitle**' and '**videoOwnerChannelId**' to the snippet section.
Now you can get both values directly in a playlistitems list request.

I just upgraded (using the .NET/C# lib of the Youtube API) from 1.30 to 1.50.
Then I got it to work. Had that same issue.